# sendto api in udp for linux operating system?

Tags: c, linux, api, sockets, udp

```
int acceptSocket;
char buf[100];
long sentbytes;
socklen_t len;
int port = 18227;

int CreateSocket()
{
    long rc;
    struct sockaddr_in addr, client;

       // Socket creation for UDP
       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)
       {
         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");
         return 1;
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Socket started!\n");
       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port=htons(port);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)
     {
       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
     }

     while(rc!=-1)
         {
         len =sizeof(client);
         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }

         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );

            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
                makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
                makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
          }

       close(acceptSocket);
       return 0;
     }

int main()
{
     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}

//API for sending the data to the client.
void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;

        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
}
```

I created a server side program for receiving data from the client and sending the response back to the client. I am able to receive data from the client via the recvfrom api but later I have to send the response back to the client via sendto api within the XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes ); (This is the api supported in my project for transmitting the data). Client is a tool for sending the data to the specified port and ip address. Can I use again  struct sockaddr_in client; in the Transmit api ?? could some one help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct sockaddr_in client;` is you used in transmit API which is wrong where it is initialized?

So you must used initilized socket structure. from your above code you can received successfuly data from client but not able to send because your `client` structure in transmit function is `NULL` nothing initilized so where to go?

You can do something like this

```
rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

sendto(acceptSocket,buf,rc,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client));
```

Or pass the `client` structure to the your transmit function as follows

```
void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes,struct sockaddr* client )
{
        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
}
```

Comment: struct sockaddr_in client;  // this is initialized within the XcpApp_IpTransmit () api. I cant add or modify the parameters within the XcpApp_IpTransmit api.

Comment: if i make it as a global variable struct sockaddr_in client and can I use the same in both sendto and recvfrom api ??

Comment: @user3345539 in transmit API you just declared `client` not initialize it, your initialization done in `CreateSocket` API.So you can either take it global and use it in both send and recv api or pass the reference of `client` to send API.

Answer (score 0):

This shall work. When you are working with `SOCK_DGRAM`, you can always send data back, using the received address (and it's size, in general case). Exceptions, of course, include cases, when the peer socket become unavailable.

Alternatively, if you have only one client, you can use `connect` to set the default remote peer address and `send` will use it:

```
sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t len;

len = sizeof(addr);
x = recvfrom(socket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len);
connect(socket, (struct sockaddr*)addr, len);
...
send(socket, buf, bufsize, 0);
send(socket, buf, bufsize, 0);
send(socket, buf, bufsize, 0);
```

One comment, though. You are using AF_INET and your code will work correctly. But you can make it compatible with other protocols as well. For that:

```
sockadd_storage addr;
socklen_t len;

len = sizeof(addr);
x = recvfrom(socket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len);
...
sendto(socket,buf,bufsize,0,(struct sockaddr*)addr, len);
```

This type of code will work with any datagram protocol including AF_LOCAL and AF_INET6.

Comment: can i use send instead of sendto ??

Comment: @user3345539 If you used `connect`, than yes

Comment: there is only 5 parameters in sendto api. Is that right ?

Comment: I am using AF_INET . it is for IPV4. can i use the above code  (second code)??

Comment: @user3345539 Depending on your needs. If your server works in strict single-threaded request-response mode, you _may_ use `connect`. In all other cases you have to use `sendto`.